# Typescript get object outside the function

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function for creating a new firebase user.
I want to get the user object (created by this function) outside the function, but when i try to console.log it, i get "undefined" in the console.

```
async saveProfile(){

const secondaryApp = this.firebase.initializeApp(this.config,"appname2");
var X;

try {


  secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.em, this.pwd)
  .then(function test(firebaseUser) {


    X = firebaseUser;

    //Here I CAN GET THE OBJECT X
    console.log(X);
    secondaryApp.auth().signOut();

  })
    //I WANT TO GET THE X OBJECT HERE !!
    //BUT I GET "UNDEFINED"
    console.log(X);
}

catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    this.toast.create({
      message: e.message,
      duration: 3000
    }).present();
  }     
}
```

sorry if the quetion is somewhat stupid but i'm beginner especially using typescript. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code outside the `.then()` runs before the Promise (returned by `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`) completes.

You have to wait for it, that's why the `console.log(X)` inside the `.then()` handle works.

#### Solution:

Since you are inside an `async` function, you can use `await`:

```
async saveProfile() {
  const secondaryApp = this.firebase.initializeApp(this.config, "appname2");
  var X;

  try {
    // added await below
    X = await secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.em, this.pwd);
    secondaryApp.auth().signOut(); 
    console.log(X);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    this.toast.create({
      message: e.message,
      duration: 3000
    }).present();
  }
}
```

Comment: it works now
thanks for the explanation and for the fast solution.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped. Thanks for accepting as well. JSYK i think you just gained enough reputation for upvotes. Congratz!